# Getting the lat and long of a click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, planetary.js

Is there a way to get the latitude and longitude when a user click somewhere on a planetary.js globe? It's not in the planetary.js API, but is there a way to do it in d3.js? If there isn't how hard would it be to implement the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further digging into the D3 API if found that `projection.invert([x,y])` returns `[long,lat]` of the supplied coordinates.